# Which site is best to ask a question about web proxies?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question about how to use a web proxy to access a server in a different network.

Which is the best Stack Exchange site for this question?

Comment: Sounds like either serverfault or super user could fit, depending if that web proxy is part of an enterprisy network or not. But your question is unclear /  generic that exact advice is not possible. Please read the tag wiki of [site-recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info) what we minimal need to offer better advice

Comment: Thanks. Yeah - I was scratching my head about how to tag this. I have never asked a meta question before.... I’ll give serverfault a go.

Comment: Please do read their help center before you post there: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic